# Fitting of peaks with constraint condition of same area

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, fitting

If I have the following data:

https://pastebin.com/RFVd0MpU

Which plotted between 60 to 100 (celsius) using the following code, gives:

```
ListLinePlot[datawithnoliquidline, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 PlotRange -> {{60, 110}, {-0.5, All}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> 14, Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {"T (\[Degree]C)", 
     Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(P\)]\)", " (", " J/gK)"}]}), 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 14}]
```

[image]

**Questions:**

1. How can I fit the two peaks in the opposite directions (see image below) knowing that both peaks have the same area?
2. How can I find the area of both peaks?.

**Note** the baseline for both peaks is at zero.

[image]

**This is my approach so far. As you can see I am close but I am hoping someone here can help me improve what is missing:**

```
ma5guess = 5;
siga5guess = 8;
ma3guess = 1.3;
siga3guess = 3;
meda3guess = 97;
meda5guess = 75;

ff2[x_, areaa3_, areaa5_, siga3_, meda3_, meda5_, siga5_] := 
  areaa3 PDF[NormalDistribution[meda3, siga3], x] - 
   areaa5 PDF[SkewNormalDistribution[meda5, siga5, -5], x] ;

nlm3 = NonlinearModelFit[
   datawithnoliquidline, {ff2[x, areaa3, areaa5, siga3, meda3, meda5, 
     siga5], areaa3 >=  0, meda3 - 2*siga3 > 80, 
    68 < meda5 - 2*siga5 < meda3 - 2*siga3}, {{areaa3, 
     ma3guess}, {areaa5, ma5guess}, {siga3, siga3guess}, {meda3, 
     meda3guess}, {meda5, meda5guess}, {siga5, siga5guess}}, x];

fp = nlm3["BestFitParameters"];

p1 =(*Original data*)
  ListLinePlot[datawithnoliquidline, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
   PlotRange -> {{40, 110}, {-0.5, All}}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> 14, Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
   FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {"T (\[Degree]C)", 
       Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(P\)]\)", " (", " J/gK)"}]}), 
   LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 14}];

p2b = Plot[{nlm3[x], 
    areaa3 PDF[NormalDistribution[meda3, siga3], x] /. 
     fp, -areaa5 PDF[SkewNormalDistribution[meda5, siga5, -5], x] /. 
     fp}, {x, 40, 110}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashing[{0.02, 0.04}], 
      AbsoluteThickness[5]], Directive[Green, AbsoluteThickness[2]], 
     Directive[Orange, AbsoluteThickness[2]]}, PlotRange -> All];

Show[p1, p2b]
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: I believe your problem is ill-posed. If you could prescribe the shape of the peak (for instance a Gaussian curve) and the two ranges where you want to fit them, then you could minimize a cost without two much difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fit to the data:

```
f[x_] = p1 Exp[-(x - p2)^2 p3] + p4 Exp[-(x - p5)^2 p6] /. 
  FindFit[dat1, 
   p1 Exp[-(x - p2)^2 p3] + p4 Exp[-(x - p5)^2 p6], {p1, {p2, 75}, p3,
     p4, {p5, 90}, p6}, x]
Plot[f[x], {x, dat1[[1, 1]], dat1[[-1, 1]]}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.001], Point[dat1]}]
```

[image]

The areas you can get from:

```
{f1[x_], f2[x_]} = {p1 Exp[-(x - p2)^2 p3], 
    p4 Exp[-(x - p5)^2 p6]} /. 
   FindFit[dat1, 
    p1 Exp[-(x - p2)^2 p3] + p4 Exp[-(x - p5)^2 p6], {p1, {p2, 75}, 
     p3, p4, {p5, 90}, p6}, x];
Integrate[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 60, 110}]
(*{-1.35076, 1.02609}*)
```

However, note that the your assumptions of "the baseline for both peaks is at zero" is obviously not right.

Comment: Daniel, thank you very much for your answer. However, when I put your code as it is and change the name of the data to "dat1" and get "FindFit::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.". Also the peak 1 seems to be cut and it is unclear the fit for that peak. Did you cut the data or use it as it was in the post?

Comment: Hi John,I did only use data from approx. 70 to 115 degree.  I tried to reproduce it. I copied/pasted your data: dat0={{...},{...},...} Then I take a part: dat1 = dat0[[2400 ;; 3800]];   Then the result from the fit  is: {p1 -> -0.107358, p2 -> 75.6448, p3 -> 0.0198087, p4 -> 0.170771, 
 p5 -> 89.1813, p6 -> 0.0870177}

Comment: The reason that I did not take all the data is, that the baseline is obviously not constant.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your explanation. Now, I understand what you did. I understand that while peak 2 is very easy to see, peak 1 is not very clear and hence it is neccesary some approach where the data fitting goes beyond the data where the peak will be concave up towards zero (as in the red curve I drew). That's the reason I said that the baseline for both peaks is zero. In your approach, you can fit very well peak 2, but for peak 1 you are only fitting what you see in the curve and not an expected "exotherm" peak similar to the red curve. Does this make sense?

Comment: You can see it as the two peaks are really convoluted and they happen to be in different directions. So, for instance, if you have convoluted peaks in the same direction, you usually only see a small signature of it but when you do the deconvolution you can clearly see the whole peak. It's the same here. The two peaks are convoluted in opposite directions and peak 1 is concave up (touching zero) from around 70 to 80-83C.

Comment: Try subtracting a base line to make the base more constant, then the fit should be easier.

Comment: Daniel, take a look at my approach (I just put it above) to see what I told you about the two peaks being convoluted. Perhaps with that you can help me?

Comment: Hi John, I do not think this is correct. You are fitting two functions with  baselines of zero to some data that has a very curved baseline. To judge the fit you need to plot the error. And the error will be bad because your data has a very konvex baseline, you can not simply ignore this. The thing to do is to first subtract the baseline, then do the fit and then add the baseline again. Another approach is to use fit-functions that do not assume a baseline of zero.  Note, the word convolution has another meaning than you think, look it up. I think you mean overlay.

Comment: Daniel thanks for your comment. How could I subtract a "good" baseline? How can I plot the error?

Comment: That's "handwork". You could use e.g. some spline (read about it in the help, there are several different variety ). They have "control points," with which you can form a smooth curve of arbitrary shape. This can be done in e.g. a LocatorPane or in a Manipulate, but this will need some coding. When you have the curve, you calculate its value at the data points and subtract it. It would be easier if you know what determines the baseline, but in practice, this is often not the case.

Comment: Here is another idea that is simpler but more error prone. Try adding a function that describes the baseline to your fit functions. This increases the number of parameters to fit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that you can adapt to your data for fitting a spline to given points. This example fits a curve to points from a Morse potential. You can move the locator to adapt the function:

```
pts = {{0, 10}, {1, 5}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 5}, {7, 5.5}, {8, 6}};(*data points. Do not use too many data points, otherwise you will slow down the graphics*)
loc = {{1, 4}, {2, 1}, {4, 1}, {6, 3}, {7, 4}};(*locators*)
DynamicModule[{},
 Dynamic@Show[
   Graphics[{Locator[Dynamic[loc[[1]]]], Locator[Dynamic[loc[[2]]]], 
     Locator[Dynamic[loc[[3]]]], Locator[Dynamic[loc[[4]]]], 
     Locator[Dynamic[loc[[5]]]], 
     spline = 
      BezierCurve[Join[{pts[[1]]}, loc, {pts[[-1]]}], 
       SplineDegree -> (Length@loc + 1)], {PointSize[0.02], Red, 
      Point[pts]}}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 10}, {-5, 12}}],
   ParametricPlot[spline[x], {x, 0, 10}]
   ]]
```

[image]

If you finally got the points in "loc" you can make a function that you can use to subtract the baseline:

```
bf = BezierFunction[Join[{pts[[1]]}, loc, {pts[[-1]]}]];
fun = Interpolation[Table[bf[t], {t, 0, 1, 0.05}]];
Plot[fun[x], {x, pts[[1, 1]], pts[[-1, 1]]}]
```