# Subtract peaks from curve

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, fitting

If I have the following data:

https://pastebin.com/2jgDw4iQ

which plotted using the following code

```
ListLinePlot[data, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 PlotRange -> {{70, 110}, {-0.2, All}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> 14, Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {"T (\[Degree]C)", 
     Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(P\)]\)", " (", " J/gK)"}]}), 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 14}]
```

gives:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. How can remove the two peaks (see image below for clarification) of the curve to obtain exactly the same curve without those two peaks?

The two peaks, represented in blue and green (not very well fitted, but to give you an idea), are as shown in the figure below:

[image]

**Another way to ask the same is:** How can I remove the two peaks so that instead of peaks I simply have a line at zero in the region where the peaks are located?.

2. How can I subtract only the peak 1 (in blue) or only the peak 2 (in green) while leaving the other intact?

**Note: The baseline for the two peaks of opposite directions is at zero.**

Comment: Are you asking about some sort of ["de-trending"](https://www.google.com/search?&q=detrending+of+a+time+series&oq=detrending+of+a+time+series) ?

Comment: Here is a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/233350).

Comment: @AntonAntonov thank you for your commnet. The related question that you posted was posted by me before and it it a very very very different question. In that question I was asking about how to fit those two peaks (with a different data set). In this one, I am asking how to remove those two peaks.

Comment: "The related question that you posted was posted by me before [...]" -- That is totally fine. I mentioned that other question in a comment so its page to be explicitly linked to this one by MSE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below I am using the software monad [`QRMon`](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/), but the code can be relatively easily modified to use the resource function [`QuantileRegression`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/QuantileRegression).

### Data

```
data = Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/2jgDw4iQ"];
```

### Definitions

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicQuantileRegression.m"]
```

```
Clear[MyDetrending];
MyDetrending[data_, knots_ : 16, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{lsDefaultOpts = Sequence @@ {PlotTheme -> "Detailed", AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> Large}},
   QRMonUnit[data]⟹
    QRMonQuantileRegression[knots, 0.5]⟹
    QRMonPlot[PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8], PointSize[0.008]}, lsDefaultOpts, opts]⟹
    QRMonErrorPlots["RelativeErrors" -> False, Filling -> False, Joined -> True, lsDefaultOpts, opts]
   ];
```

### De-trending with QRMon

#### Global de-trending

> How can I remove the two peaks so that instead of peaks I simply have a line at zero in the region where the peaks are located?.

Filter the data to adhere to question’s plots:

```
data2 = Select[data, 75 <= #[[1]] <= 110 &];
ResourceFunction["RecordsSummary"][data2]
```

[image]

De-trend the (filtered) data:

```
qrObj1 = MyDetrending[data2];
```

[image]

[image]

Get the corresponding values:

```
deTrendedData = (qrObj1\[DoubleLongRightArrow]QRMonErrors[
      "RelativeErrors" -> 
       False]\[DoubleLongRightArrow]QRMonTakeValue)[0.5];
ListLinePlot[deTrendedData]
```

[image]

#### Local de-trending

> How can I subtract only the peak 1 (in blue) or only the peak 2 (in green) while leaving the other intact?

Getting a local trend:

```
qrObj2 = MyDetrending[Select[data, 79 <= #[[1]] <= 88 &], 4, "Echo" -> False];
qFunc = (qrObj2\[DoubleLongRightArrow]QRMonTakeRegressionFunctions)[0.5];
```

Localized de-trending:

```
deTrendedDataLocal1 =  Map[If[79 <= #[[1]] <= 88, {#[[1]], #[[2]] - qFunc[#[[1]]]}, #] &, data2];
ListLinePlot[deTrendedDataLocal1, Sequence @@ {PlotTheme -> "Detailed", AspectRatio -> 1/2,  ImageSize -> Large}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Anton, yes, it seems that way. Thank you!. From question 1, pretty much if I get exactly the same curve but instead of both peaks I get a line around zero (which is when the two peaks are subtracted, then that works.

Comment: Anton, thank you very much. This looks great. But I have two questions: 1) Where is the rest of the data of the curve from 20 all the way to around 75? or from 110 to 120?2) How can I also remove the second peak?. I would like to have the same exact intact data that I posted but without the two peaks. From what I can see or understand, only the data from around 76 to 110 is there.

Comment: Anton, never mind the last comment. I was able to figure out the two questions I asked. Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it !

Answer (score 1):

As a product of visual inspection, taking data from $\approx 80$ to $120$ and using the model

$$
f(a,b,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,x_1,x_2,x)=a e^{-\left(\frac{x-x_1}{\sigma_1}\right)^2}+b e^{-\left(\frac{x-x_2}{\sigma_2}\right)^2}
$$

```
data = Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/2jgDw4iQ"];
reddata = Take[data, {990, Length[data]}];

f[a_, s1_, x1_, x_] := a Exp[-((x - x1)/s1)^2]
f[a_, b_, s1_, s2_, x1_, x2_, x_] := f[a, s1, x1, x] + f[b, s2, x2, x]
obj = Sum[(reddata[[k, 2]] - f[a, b, s1, s2, x1, x2, reddata[[k, 1]]])^2, {k, 1, Length[reddata]}];
sol = NMinimize[{obj, x2 > 90, x1 > 80, Abs[a] < 0.08, Abs[b] < 0.08}, {a, b, s1, s2, x1, x2}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

gr1 = Plot[fxk[x], {x, 75.5, 120}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}];
gr2 = ListPlot[reddata, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

[image]

Following with

```
datat = Transpose[reddata];
xk = datat[[1, All]];
fxk0 = Map[fxk, xk];
f10 = Map[f1, xk];
f20 = Map[f2, xk];
data0 = Transpose[{xk, fxk0}];
data1 = Transpose[{xk, f10}];
data2 = Transpose[{xk, f20}];
datacorr = reddata - fxk0;
datacorr1 = reddata - f10;
datacorr2 = reddata - f20;
ListLinePlot[datacorr, PlotStyle -> Blue]
ListLinePlot[datacorr1, PlotStyle -> Blue]
ListLinePlot[datacorr2, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

Here we can observe three plots.

The first is the data without both bumps

[image]

The second is the data without the first bump.

[image]

and the third is the data without the last bump.

[image]